# Maven error "Unable to initialize main class" when I try to run a jar file I just created

Tags: java, maven, jar

I created a .jar file using Maven in the command line. It created the .jar file. When I tried to run it in the command line I got this error:

```
java -jar target\github-automation-1.0.0.jar
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.aking.app.Application
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

I am not sure how to fix this issue. This is the file structure showing where important files are located (package is combined for the sake of typing):

```
- githubautomation (root directory)
    - pom.xml
    - src
        - main
            - java
                - com.aking.app
                    - Applicatoin.java

    - target
        - classes
            - com.aking.app
                - Application.class
        - github-automation-1.0.0.jar
```

My pom.xml (Edit: added suggested code)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <start-class>com.aking.app.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <groupId>com.aking.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>github-automation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.aking.app.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I also read something that there needs to be a main manifest attribute, but I'm not sure. I want to be able to have people run my program through the jar without relying on them to have an IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the root cause of your problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

The class loader cannot find the `WebDriver` class.

Why?

Probably because the JAR file containing the class is not on the **runtime** classpath.

So how do you get it on the classpath?

There are 3 ways:

1. Use `java -cp ... com.aking.app.Application` where the `...` has all of the JAR files that you need.  The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) explains the syntax you need to use to express the classpath on the command line.

   Note: on Linux and Mac OS, the classpath separator is `:` not `;`.
2. Modify your JAR file to include a `Class-Path` attribute in its MANIFEST.MF file.
3. Create an "UberJAR" that contains an exploded copy of all dependent JARs.

Variations 2 and 3 can be done using Maven.

Comment: How would I add it to the runtime classpath?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify your start class in pom.xml.
In the properties section, include the below line

```
 <start-class>#path to your main class</start-class>
```

The path should be relative, i.e from the start of your package name.

Comment: Would that be the "Application.class" in the target directory or "Applicaton.java" in the src directory.

Comment: It should be the one in src directory

Comment: I added     <start-class>com.aking.app.Application</start-class>
and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Yup.  This is NOT what is causing the problem.  The root cause is indicated by the stacktrace.